Does this parametrized space curve (or similar) have a name?
My son has a chandelier in his family room that is a space curve with trilateral symmetry, and I'm wondering if this curve has a name (or alternatively, if it belongs to a named class). I won't bother showing the light itself because it looks almost exactly like this:

You can click on the "like this" link to view it from different angles, I believe. I've looked in a few lists—notably the list of space curves on Wikipedia—and haven't found it yet, although it is a bit related to the space cardioid. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Blue in the comments points out that this is (or is at least close to) a geodesic on a torus.

Is it perhaps a particular geodesic on the torus (via Mark L. Irons on rdrop.com)?

@Blue: I think it sort of is. It is, at the very least, what results from wrapping a string around a donut three times and returning to your starting point. This becomes more evident as you increase the number of lobes.

If instead of $4/3+\cos(3t)$ we write $2+\cos(3t)$ and we delete the negative sign on the $y$ coordinate, we get a really similar curve, which is in fact a $(1,3)$-torus knot. It is a trivial knot (it is already unknotted), since $p=1$.

@JulioPuerta: That's good enough for me for a name, thanks! The $4/3$ and the negative sign were put there simply to match the appearance of the chandelier as closely as possible. It's $4/3$ instead of $2$ because the lobes meet closer in the middle, and the negative sign is there to change the handedness. Want to write that in an answer and I'll accept it?

@BrianTung Sure, will do.

@JulioPuerta: Note that actually the negative sign should just be moved to the $z$ coordinate to match the form given at that article.

@BrianTung True; that does not affect the general shape of the curve much since $\sin(3t)$ takes on all values from $-1$ to $1$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$.

@JulioPuerta: I've changed the form I've shown in the original post to better match what's in the torus knot article. You may want to adjust your answer to suit that.

Copy of my previous comment, made an answer per OP's suggestion.
If on your parametrization we write $2+\cos(3t)$ instead of $4/3+\cos(3t)$,
we get a really similar curve, which is in fact a $(1,3)$
-torus knot. It is a trivial knot (it is already unknotted), since $p=1$ (where $p$ is as per the notation used in the linked article).
